# Send an array of items to paypal checkout

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

How can I send the items that I already have stored in a collection to the paypal checkout, I already have the whole process integrated, but at the moment it only works with the test items offered by PayPal, I have not been able to integrate my own collection of items.

**My cart Items**

I have my items like this:

```
 $items = Session::get('items'); //Json
 $decoded_items= json_decode($items,true); //decoded to array
```

If I `return $items` I have the whole collection:

```
{

"Items":[
          {
            "id":1,
            "inventoryID":1,
            "title":"Product 1",
            "quantity":1,
            "unit_price":20,
            "image":"img.png"
          },

          {
            "id":2,
            "inventoryID":1,
            "title":"Product2",
            "quantity":1,
            "unit_price":25,
            "image":"img.png"
           }
        ],
    "items_count":2,
    "products_count":2
}
```

But if I `return $decoded_items['Items'];` I just got the array:

```
[
          {
            "id":1,
            "inventoryID":1,
            "title":"Product 1",
            "quantity":1,
            "unit_price":20,
            "image":"img.png"
          },

          {
            "id":2,
            "inventoryID":1,
            "title":"Product2",
            "quantity":1,
            "unit_price":25,
            "image":"img.png"
           }
   ]
```

**The paypal example**

The paypal example works fine, and is:

```
    $item1 = new Item();
    $item1->setName('Ground Coffee 40 oz')
        ->setCurrency('USD')
        ->setQuantity(1)
        ->setSku("123123") // Similar to `item_number` in Classic API
        ->setPrice(7.5);
    $item2 = new Item();
    $item2->setName('Granola bars')
        ->setCurrency('USD')
        ->setQuantity(5)
        ->setSku("321321") // Similar to `item_number` in Classic API
        ->setPrice(2);

    $itemList = new ItemList();
    $itemList->setItems(array($item1,$item2));
```

**I tried**

And with this example in mind and the way I'm getting mine items I tried:

```
    $items = Session::get('items');
    $decoded_items= json_decode($items,true);

    foreach($decoded_items['Items'] as $element) {
        $name=$element['title'];
        $quantity=$element['quantity'];
        $sku= $element['id'];
        $price=$element['unit_price'];

        $item = new Item();
        $item-> setName($name)
        ->setCurrency('USD')
        ->setQuantity($quantity)
        ->setSku($sku) // Similar to `item_number` in Classic API
        ->setPrice($price);
        $results[] = $item;
    }

$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems($results);
```

but sending mine items the paypal pay window just never open.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Are the JSON dumps above copy and paste, or did you type them out manually?  I ask because you're missing a comma after `"Product2 "` in both instances.

Comment: thank you, just fix it, the structure is copied, but the names are writed by hand

Comment: The `json_decode` works fine on my end for the corrected JSON with your code above.  The only other thing I see at first glance is that you're passing an integer to `->setSku()` when it appears to accept a string in the example.  You might try casting it with `(string) $sku`.  Beyond that, you are going to need to provide more code.

Comment: What else you think that I need to provide about my code?

Comment: You mention the syntax error.  Is that actually stopping anything from running or is it just an IDE warning?  Can you successfully dump `dd($results)` after the PayPal data is defined, or is the code being halted before you get there?  Do you have any errors in your logs?  If there are no problems here, then it sounds like the problem could be in the way you're providing the data to PayPal, which you have not provided in your current post — i.e., more code.

Comment: Also, your PayPal example shouldn't work.  You have defined `$item1` and `$item2`, but then say `$itemList->setItems(array($item));`.  Where does `$item` come from?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was cheching the syntax error, but not sure whats cause it, but is not becouse of the paypal function, is like stacked on one line of my code (so weird) And you rigth, I wrote wrong my paypal example, I just edited it, but that example is working perfect, thats why I didnt post the way as I send it to paypal, cause the example is working, I realize it was just a way to write the array (as the example)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199658/discussion-between-matticustard-and-wilson-guerrero).

Answer (score 0):

There may be two major reason for such kind of issues on `Paypal` please check below:

1. Check your subTotal, tax, shipping in case of single item and multiple items and its sum should be equal to total i.e `subTotal + tax + shipping = total`
2. Check your `returnUrl` and `cancelUrl` there should be no space and special character use `urlencode` for this.